# Command line to trace product backlog item from label appied to source code

Tags: tfs

For my project requirement i have applied the label to source code modified in TFS2010.Now at the time of build i am supplying file name to do the build and deployment and these files are getting picked up as per label applied.But this approach will not tell me which file was modified in which backlog.Is there any commnd line available in TFS to get the product backlog item asscociated with the files modified be developer?

Answer (score 0):

In build definition you have the parameter Associate Changesets and Work Items (under the Process tab and in the Advanced node); this parameter should be set to true

Answer (score 0):

If your development team has been checking-in changes and associating each checkin with the relevent Work Item then the data is in there. The build by default will update the Integrated In value in the related work item, and in 2012+ all parent work items. So if you have been doing that the data is there.

There is however no OOB report to retrieve it. You can use the API or the Warehouse to get the data out.